# How to implement one BroadcasReceiver and another acitivity both as a Launcher activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have two launcher activities,
1. Receiver activity which is a Broadcast Receiver.
2. An Activity which should be main Launcher activity.

When an SMS arrives the receiver activity launches the `.MainActivity`(BroadcastReceiver) and it further start one service. (Without GUI) and without opening `Settings` activity.
Another activity `.Settings` is Main launcher activity.

**Goal I want to Achive:**
When sms arrived `receiver` activity work as it is. But When I want to change the settings `Setting` activity starts.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.aa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.aa.FindLocation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.aa.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.aa.Settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.aa.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:enabled="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".Servc" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.Servc" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Problem**
**1.**
    [2014-07-06 02:55:14 - Aa] Uploading Aa.apk onto device 'S5830f4524b76'
    [2014-07-06 02:55:14 - Aa] Installing Aa.apk...
    [2014-07-06 02:55:18 - Aa] Success!
    [2014-07-06 02:55:18 - Aa] Starting activity com.example.aa.Settings on device S5830f4524b76
    [2014-07-06 02:55:19 - Aa] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.aa/.Settings }
**2.**
What changes should be made in manifest to make it working?

Comment: What do you mean " When an SMS arrives the receiver activity launches the .MainActivity". I do not see any "receiver activity" in your manifest. I think you mean ".MainActivity starts when an sms is received".

Answer (score 0):

Don't define your sms receiver in the manifest. Remove it.

Create Broadcast receiver that runs on boot up by defining the below element in your manifest :

```
<receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You will need to add this permission to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Then register your sms receiving BroadcastReceiver in there :

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SmsReceiver smsreceiver = new SmsReceiver();        
        IntentFilter fltr_smsreceived = new IntentFilter(
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            registerReceiver(smsreceiver, fltr_smsreceived);
        }
    }
```

`SmsReceiver` is your broadcast receiver. For example :

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    void setActivityHandler(){
        //instantiate member variables if required
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle pdusBundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus=(Object[])pdusBundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage messages=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
        Log.d("tag","message body : " + messages.getMessageBody());
    }


}
```

Comment: [2014-07-06 04:47:04 - Aa] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.aa/.Settings }

Comment: SmsReceiver is not predefined class... What should be inside `SmsReceiver` ?

Comment: replace `SmsReceiver` with your sms BroadcastReceiver class. It should be `MainActivity` in your case.